# If $2^{12^{7}+3}\equiv x \pmod{36}$, then what is the value of $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> If $2^{12^{7} + 3} \equiv x \pmod{36}$, then what is the value of $x$?

We have:

$$
\begin{align}
2^5 & \equiv - 4 \pmod{36} \\
2^{10} & \equiv 16 \pmod{36} \\
2^{12} & \equiv - 8 \pmod{36} \\
(2^{12})^{12} & \equiv 8^{12} \pmod{36} \\
2^{12^2} & \equiv - 8 \pmod{36} \text{, as } 8^{12} \equiv - 8 \pmod{36} \\
(2^{12^2})^{12^5} & \equiv - 8 \pmod{36} \\
2^{12^7} & \equiv - 8 \pmod{36} \\
2^{{12^7} + 3} & \equiv - 64 \pmod{36} \\
2^{{12^7} + 3} & \equiv 8 \pmod{36} \\
\end{align}
$$

Am I right or wrong? Is there any simpler way to find it?

Comment: $x=2^{12^7+3}$ works.

Comment: A good theorem for this kind of equations is $\textbf{Euler-Fermat's Little Theorem}$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Except you should also prove your statement $8^{12}\equiv -8\pmod {36}$, which is correct but not proved.

Comment: Yes...I can prove it..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It is a trivial proof once you observe that $8\cdot 8\equiv -8\pmod {36}$ (so $8^2\equiv -8, 8^3\equiv 8, 8^4\equiv -8, 8^5\equiv 8,\ldots,8^{12}\equiv -8$).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to work modulo $4$ and modulo $9$, and use [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

First we have
$$x \equiv 2^{12^{7}+3}\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$

To compute
$$x \equiv 2^{12^{7}+3} \pmod{9},$$
it suffices to compute $12^{7} + 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$, as $6 = \varphi(9)$. (Or, if you prefer, as $2^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$.) So
$$2^{12^{7}+3}\equiv 2^{3} \equiv 8 \pmod{9}.$$

Clearly, then, the solution is indeed $x = 8$ as you found it, as $8 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

We need $x \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,35\}$ such that $2^{12^7+3} = 36M + x$. Note that $4$ divides $2^{12^7+3}$ and $36M$. Hence, $x$ must be a multiple of $4$, say $4y$. We now need $y$ such that
$$2^{12^7+1} = 9M + y$$
where $y \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,8\}$. Since $\gcd(2,9) = 1$, we have $$2^{\phi(9)} \equiv 1 \pmod9 \implies 2^6 \equiv 1\pmod9$$
We have $12^7+1 = 6t+1$. Hence,
$$2^{12^7} \equiv 1 \pmod9 \implies 2^{12^7+1} \equiv 2 \pmod9$$
Hence, $y=2$, which gives us that $x=8$.